# How to prevent iOS from dimming or changing the screen brightness

Tags: ios, display

I have the "Display & Brightness" feature of iOS disabled, and yet the device still dims to a brightness level that is unreadable after about 10secs of inactivity.. How do I turn this off?

Answer (score 1):

iOS dims the display just before the Auto-Lock period.

You can set this period in Settings → General → Auto-Lock.

However, if Settings → Battery → Low Power Mode is set to on, the regular auto-lock setting is disregarded.

Comment: No probs! The very short amount of time that @erikvold mentioned made me suspect that low power mode might be the culprit - it sets the auto lock to 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same trouble with this. My auto-lock was already turned off, but my phone continued to keep dimming and I couldn't figure out why.

I eventually realized my power-saving mode was on which makes it dim automatically. Make sure yours is off: Settings > Battery > Low Power Mode > Off

- Iphone 6 user

Answer (score -1):

You can't. I have my autolock set on after 5 minutes and it auto dims the screen after about a minute, unless I'm watching a video. But if my phone is plugged in, I don't have a problem with the screen dimming.

Answer (score -2):

settings > general > accessibility > Display accommodations > Auto Brightness > off

Comment: This doesn't change the inactivity delay experienced by OP

Comment: This one is the one I was looking for, if I'm between the device and the source of light, it starts dimming.